# Scraping Instagram Data with Requests and BS (NEW)

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests

first off I want to not there are posts on how to do this the old way using meta tags, but for whatever reason meta tags won't work anymore and I've seen using json can work somehow but I'm not very familiar with json. Like at all. I kind of modified what I had to work for this but still nothing. The goal is simply just to get the number of followers of an account (user).

```
def follower_amt(self, user):
    time.sleep(6)     
    # old method deprecated
    # now requires using json file
    html = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{user}/?__a=1')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    data = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'g47SY'})
    text = data[0].get('content').split()
    user = '%s %s %s' % (text[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
    followers = text[0]
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can this info not come from an API? Also, can you give an example full url and expected return value

Comment: @QHarr Instagram deprecated their API a good while ago so we must resort to this. An example URL is just https://www.instagram.com/brandonator24/ and the appended '?__a=1' is from what I read about using json which again, I'm not familiar with. It should return a byte string of the number of followers, however that's just what I had but that could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NOTE: Not tested as doubt scraping is allowed)

I see that value in page source in script tag which means you may be able to regex out as follows:

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/brandonator24/', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0').text

print(int(re.search('"edge_follow":{"count":(\d+)}', r).groups(0)[0]))
```

This is of course a broad assumption other pages are of similar set-up.

---

Regex meaning:

[image]

Comment: It says it expected a string or bytes like object? Also I can see regex working but would like to get it to work using beautiful soup if possible. I got to this point which I think should work but doesn't

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')`
`stuff = soup.find_all('meta', name='description')`

Comment: Shouldn't say needs bytes like object as the request is to a string url and from the response object I am taking the .text which is a string. Try with adding a header as in edit.

Comment: Ok adding the headers worked! Can you explain what the headers are briefly and how the request was working before without them and not until recently?

Comment: I guess the server has now been configured to look for certain headers in requests received. This is pretty common. Read about headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Answer (score 1):

According to the ApiUrl you gave.

You can get what you want, right?

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{user}/?__a=1', headers=headers)

print(res.json()['graphql']['user']['username'])
print(res.json()['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'])
```

Comment: I ran that and it gave me a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` And I really have no experience with json before today so I'm lost. I would like to use beautiful soup if possible like before.

Comment: But my operation is OK, can you give me a UserID?

Comment: yea it's brandonator24

Comment: You probably got blocked by Instagram. There are APIs for scraping that use proxy to make requests and avoid getting blocked. Here is one of them that has a good tutorial for scraping Instagram: scrapingfish.com/blog/scraping-instagram